# Send the value of class - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Am I able to get the css class name of an OPTION element, and then add it to an input field with jQuery?

I have this now:

```
  var classChecker = $('#amount').attr('class');
  $("#classBox").html("<b>$</b> " + 
              classChecker);
```

Although this just gives me: $ undefined

Comment: By `add to an input field` do you mean, set the input fields value to the class, or add the actual class to the input?

Comment: I mean set the input fields value to that class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get the class of an element:

```
$('selector').attr('class');
```

*(You can use either **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** or [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to accomplish this)*

If you wanted to automate this, such as adding it to an input upon selection:

```
$("[SelectElement]").change(function(){
    $("[InputElement]").val($(this + ":selected").attr('class'));               
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bakvr/2/)**

Comment: Ahhh! Don't use `.text()` for an input element!

Comment: Doh! Didn't even realize, Thanks Neal :)

Comment: What if I wish to get the class of the OPTION element? This does not work:
      var classChecker = $('#amount').attr('class');
      $("#classBox").html("<b>$</b> " + 
                  classChecker);

Comment: I added an example, which should give you an example of how to use and grab the selected element from an option and place that into an input.

Comment: @user169691: the reason your code doesn't work is because you cannot use .html('sometext') on an input element. This would work for DIV or SPAN, but an INPUT element just cant containt HTML code

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Yes you are able to.

Why do you ask?

---

### Side point:

```
$('#inputselector').val($('#optionselector').attr('class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

```
var optionclass = $('option').prop('class');
$('input').addClass(optionclass);
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you will want to use `prop`. If you are <1.7 then use `attr`.

If you post your html then a more specific answer for your use case could be devised.

Answer (score 0):

```
var className = $('option#someid').attr('class');
$('input#someid').addClass(className);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to cut through the facetious answers and give you an example:

```
$("input#id").addClass($("option#id").prop("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting undefined as a result of `.attr('class')` it'll be because the element doesn't have a class specified...